# Overleaf's shortcut to go from code to PDF viewer

Tags: overleaf

I didn't find a keyboard shortcut to go from code to PDF viewer in Overleaf's full mode. Is there any?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This question should better be asked at the Overleaf support, it's off-topic in this site. Most people here probably don't know much about Overleaf, so you'll have better luck there.

Comment: ◦To go from your code to the corresponding place in the PDF, click the top button with the right arrow.
◦To go from the PDF to your code, click the bottom button with the left arrow.  
Simple! You can also double-click anywhere in the PDF to jump to that place in the code.

Comment: I did it, but I didn't get a asnwer yet. I have seen some questions related ot Overleaf's keyboard shortcuts in this site. That's why I tried a new one. To go from PDF to code, a double click in the PDF redirects to the code. It isn't a keyboard shortcut, but it's a great option. The other direction isn't so nice using the mouse. I'll write again if I get the answer.

Comment: I would appreciate keyboard shortcut for this too.